# Using ComplexSolver in Eigen

Tags: c++, include, eigen

I'm trying to use Eigen3 to compute some complex eigenvalues and sofar everything worked, but know I get a weird error:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3/ -Icubature/ -I/usr/include/boost/ cubature/hcubature.c main.cpp wavefunction.cpp -o main.x 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:103:2: error: ‘ComplexEigenSolver’ was not declared in this scope
  ComplexEigenSolver<MatrixXcd> ces;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:103:2: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigenvalues:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:7,
                 from main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Eigenvalues/ComplexEigenSolver.h:45:38: note:   ‘Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver’
 template<typename _MatrixType> class ComplexEigenSolver
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:103:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  ComplexEigenSolver<MatrixXcd> ces;
                              ^
main.cpp:103:32: error: ‘ces’ was not declared in this scope
  ComplexEigenSolver<MatrixXcd> ces;
                                ^~~
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

Here are my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues> 

#include "wavefunction.cpp"
#include "cubature.h"

using Eigen::MatrixXcd;
```

This is the routine where the error occurs:

```
    MatrixXcd hop(5,5);

    for(int m1 = -2; m1 <= 2; m1++){
        for(int m2 = -2; m2 <= 2; m2++){
            hop(m1+2, m2+2) = ....;
        }
    }

    ComplexEigenSolver<MatrixXcd> ces;
```

Everything works fine, only the last line doesn't work. I don't see the difference between my code and the example given at the Eigen website.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try ````Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver```` instead of just unqualified ````ComplexEigenSolver````.

Comment: In fact, the 'suggested alternative' is telling you to do just that.

Comment: My bad. I tried the other suggestions, but missed that one.

Comment: No worries. That's what we are here for. I'm attempting to find a duplicate cause I will feel bad getting answer points on this one :)

Comment: @mascoj Your first two comments are an absolute valid answer to the problem. You should not mind that the question was too simple. (I'd prefer having this question closed, so people don't have to look at it again). And @Stein (independent to your problem) if you `#include <Eigen/Dense>` you already include all dense stuff (including Eigenvalues) and Eigenvalues also includes Core. So just including `<Eigen/Eigenvalues>` would be sufficient.

Comment: @chtz I figured the same answer for a similar problem was already provided elsewhere. I have been unable to find one though.....